# I need to run macros using npm exceljs package in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, macros, exceljs

I am currently working on a NODEJS script, In which I am reading an xlsm file using the exceljs npm package. But the problem is that I need to run two macros before doing anything, The flow of the script is as follows.

- Reading the file (Done)
- Selecting a value from a DropDown Macro of excel sheet
- Enter a value in a certain cell number
- Run a Macro called Update Data
- Wait for 1 mintue
- Save that file with a different name with an extension of xlsx.

I need help with selecting the dropdown and run macro update data.

Comment: can you share some code to show, what you already tried?

Comment: `const XLSM = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
XLSM.Workbooks.Open("XFA.xlsm");
XLSM.Visible = false;
XLSM.Run("Sheet1.ImportPartData1");

async function run() {
    let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    const ANNUAL = "Annual";
    const QUARTER = "Quarterly";
    await workbook.xlsx.readFile("PK Tickers.xlsx");
    const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Worksheet");
    const values = sheet.getColumn("A").values;
    for (let i = 4; i < values.length; i++) {
        const ticker = values[i].split(" ")[0];
        console.log(ticker);
        
    }
}
run();`

Comment: I need to set ticker in the cell then click on the Marco button present in the other cell